# How to use locally updated npm package without publishing it to npm?

Tags: npm, node-modules

I'm using an `npm package` in *my-project*
and I have some updates I want to apply to that package:

- I forked the original GitHub repo, cloned, and I'm making changes to the source on my local machine
- *my-project* is still referencing the original `npm package`
- I don't want to submit a `pull request` at this point, but I do want to start using the locally updated package in *my-project*

Is there an established process for doing this locally - using the updated source in *my-project* as an npm module?

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm link`
You can use your local copy just like other packages.
[npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)